# Special relativity: time of emission of radar pulse knowing the time it was received

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

> Assume that we are in a rest system $S$ and we continuously emit radar pulses which propagate at the speed of light. At a certain time $t_0$, we receive a reflected pulse from the event with coordinates $(ct_p, x_p, 0 ,0)$. How do we determine the time of emission $t_1$ of the reflected pulse, in terms of $t_p$ and $x_p$, and the interval between the events $(ct_p, x_p, 0, 0)$ and $(0,0,0,0)$ in terms of $t_0$ and $t_1$?

I am new to special relativity, and this is an exercise regarding Minkowski diagrams. I don't know how to start drawing a Minkowski diagram or how to use it, because I don't necessarily see a second system of reference. Of course, we can draw the $x-$axis and the $ct-$axis of $S$, and the event $(ct_p, x_p, 0, 0)$ is somewhere in the "first quadrant" of this system, but I don't see how to continue.

Comment: How do you draw a reference frame of a second system if it does not move in space ?

Comment: Well, if the second system does not move in space, then its $x-$axis and the $ct-$axis are the same as the first reference frame right?

Comment: Yes, since it does not move in space it only moves in time. Now you can start to draw the path of the emitted and reflected light

Comment: I don't think I know how to draw the paths. Do you mean to say that: the event $(ct, x, 0 0)$ is somewhere in space, and that the time $ct_0$ is higher than the $c_p$ point on the $ct-$axis?

Comment: I think I am misunderstanding these concepts. What is the second reference system in this case?

Comment: Maybe this helps https://www.khanacademy.org/science/physics/special-relativity/minkowski-spacetime/v/introduction-to-special-relativity-and-minkowski-spacetime-diagrams I also did not understand the $(ct_p, x_p, 0, 0) coordinate what does it represents

Comment: I watched the video and I still don't see what is the second frame of reference. I knew that the $ct'$ and $x'$ axes of a second frame of reference make an angle of $\arctan(v/c)$ with the $ct$ and $x$ axes, respectively, if the second frame of reference moves at a speed $v$ relative to the first frame of reference. The only thing that "moves" in this exercise is the radio pulse, but it does so at the speed of light, which would make its frame of reference be just the first bisector.

Comment: Could you please further explain your solution?

Comment: In this problem, there *isn't* a second system of reference. You just have the single S frame. So now go ahead & draw your light rays.

Comment: That's what I thought, that there is no second frame of reference. However, what are the light rays? Are they just the lines connecting the point $(ct_p, x_p, 0,0)$ and the points $(ct_0,0,0,0)$ and $(ct_1,0,0,0)$, respectively?

Comment: Yes. And what do you know about light rays in a Minkowski diagram?

Comment: The speed of light is constant for both emitted and reflected pulses. Does this imply that  $ct_p$ is the middle of the segment between $ct_0$ and $ct_1$?

Comment: Actually, I don't think this is the case, since we can say that we emit pulses from the origin, and if they propagate at the speed of light, then they move along the first bisector. However, does this work for an arbitrary point $(ct_p, x_p, 0,0)$? And do we have that $ct_p$ is the middle point of the segment between the origin and $ct_0$ then?